# Recycler View not calling onBindviewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

OnBindViewHolder isn't called when I try to select an element inside the recycler view.
I'm using a horizontal layout with all the elements not showing initially (4 out of 7 elements are showing and when user motions to right the 3 elements alternate). 
Usually, when the user clicks an element OnBindViewHolder is supposed to fire but it's not happening for me. The only time it fires is on initialization. Since it doesn't fire I can't click any of the elements inside the recycler view. Maybe it might have to do with my layouts? I'm not sure

***MyAdapter***

```
public MyAdapter(){
    this.setHasStableIds(true);
}


//Set Keys
public void setSelectionTracker(SelectionTracker<Long> selectionTracker) {
    this.mSelectionTracker = selectionTracker;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView dayView, numberView;
    public View view;
    ScheduleDetails scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetails();

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        dayView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day);
        numberView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day_number);
    }

    void bind(int position, String dayInit, String numberInit, Boolean isSelected){
        scheduleDetails.position = position;
        System.out.println("Hit2: " + scheduleDetails.position);

        dayView.setText(dayInit);
        numberView.setText(numberInit);
        view.setSelected(isSelected);

    }

    public ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails(@NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent){
        return scheduleDetails;
    }
}

static class ScheduleDetails extends ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>{
    int position;
    Long identifier;

    @Override
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Long getSelectionKey() {
        return identifier;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean inSelectionHotspot(@NonNull MotionEvent e){
        return true;
    }
}

public MyAdapter(String[] day, String[] number){
    days = day;
    numbers = number;
}


@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return vh;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String dayInit = days[position];
    String numberInit = numbers[position];
    Long positions = (long) position;

    System.out.println("Position: " + position);

    boolean isSelected = false;
    if(mSelectionTracker != null){
        if(mSelectionTracker.isSelected(positions)){
            isSelected = true;
        }
        holder.bind(position, dayInit, numberInit, isSelected);
    }
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return days.length;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Where is your clickListener?

Comment: That was actually my solution to add one but I saw an example where they didn't use one. Is it necessary for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLVED***

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String dayInit = days[position];
    String numberInit = numbers[position];
    Long id = getItemId(position);

    boolean isSelected = false;
    if(mSelectionTracker != null) {
        if (mSelectionTracker.isSelected(id)) {
            isSelected = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Here: " + isSelected);
    holder.bind(position, id, dayInit, numberInit, isSelected);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

I retrieved position from getItemId and put that into my id variable (I used setHasStableIds). Click Listener isn't needed for this implementation. This is for the androidx recyclerview-selection library

Lastly I declared these in MyViewHolder:

> scheduleDetails.position = position;
>   scheduleDetails.identifier = key;

Comment: Actually clicks listeners will not fire onBindViewHolder, what will actually is will be scrolling instead, you need ot set the onclicklistener inside the bind method instead

Comment: This solution doesn't have any listeners but thanks good to know!

Comment: If you want to click on items, you will get to it

Comment: All the elements in my recycler view are clickable and can be activated/selected with this solution. For retrieving the value I just use Observer in Activity.